# Swift: Programmatically set VC frame from another VC

Tags: swift

I have two `ViewControllers` - `Slider` & `Foo`.
I am adding `Slider` as a `Foo` `subview` and setting it's frame inside `Foo` VC, but `Slider`'s frame does not change -> I can see that only `x` & `y` are applied. How should I change my code to be able to initialize `Slider` with `Slider(initWithFrame: CGFrame)`? Or what is a preferred way of setting size of `Slider` from the `Foo` VC?

// slider.swift

```
import UIKit

class Slider: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        layout.itemSize = self.view.frame.size
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 14
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cell
    }
}
```

// foo.swift

```
import UIKit

class Foo: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        slider = Slider();
        slider!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 20, height: 20)
        self.view.addSubview(slider!.view)
        self.addChildViewController(slider!)
    }

}
```

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is the *size* of your *Slider* - hopefully it's much larger in reality. 20x20 is likely way too small for a UICollectionView (and from the name, a UISlider). That said, you can code a *init(frame:)*for `Slider` - one that Swift has **always** used this, not *init(withFrame:)* - but you probably want to deal with `Slider` subview layout in it's *viewDidLoadSubviews* override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a few issues with your implementation. While it looks like the frame is not changing it actually is, but your view is not clipping to bounds, so it appears that the frame is staying the same.

A couple things to note.

First, if you're going to be setting up and laying out in code, you'll need to update your frames/placement in the func 'viewDidLayoutSubviews'. (looks like dfd mentioned this in a comment as well)

Also make sure you're implementing view controller containment correctly. Anytime you try to add the view of one view controller to the view of another view controller you should use view controller containment. Here's a link to the docs for that: [View Controller Containment Docs Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

According to Apple the minimum you should implement for containment is the following: (you got it mostly right but your calls are out of order)

```
func displayContentController(content: UIViewController) {
    addChildViewController(content)
    content.view.frame = frameForContentController()
    view.addSubview(content.view)
    content.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

I've included a UIViewController extension example in the sample below.

Try the following code, it's working for me in a test project:

```
import UIKit


class Slider: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var collectionView: UICollectionView?
var layout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout?.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    layout?.itemSize = view.bounds.size
    layout?.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout!)
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.delegate = self
    collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    // update layout item size here to your new view size
    layout?.itemSize = view.bounds.size
    // update collection view frame to new view size here
    collectionView?.frame = view.bounds

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 14
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return cell
}
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let slider = Slider()

    // note clips to bounds here, avoids confusion as to where the frame is 
    slider.view.clipsToBounds = true
    addChild(child: slider, frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 30, height: 30))
}


}


extension UIViewController {

// MARK: View Controller Containment convenience functions

func addChild(child:UIViewController, frame:CGRect) {
    // notify child of containment
    child.willMove(toParentViewController: self)

    // add content as child
    self.addChildViewController(child)

    // set frame of child content
    child.view.frame = frame

    // add childs view to hierarchy
    self.view.addSubview(child.view)

    // call containment delegate
    child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

/*
 * Call this function on a child view controller to remove it from it's parent controller and dismiss it.
 */
func remove(fromParentWithAnimationDuration animationDuration:TimeInterval)
{
    // notify child it's being removed
    self.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    // remove the view
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()

    // remove child controller from container
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I found several problems in how I created other `VC` the problem was lying there. Thanks for pointing on my mistakes. Still I have few questions regarding your answer: 1) Is it a bad practice to omit self? Like you did here ->  `view.bounds` 2) Why you used `bounds` instead of `frame`? 3) Why you place `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in the end of `func viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: Using self is not required in swift except in closures. It's more of a personal preference, I think it's cleaner without all the extra 'self's. 2) It depends on what you're going for. A views frame is it's placement inside it's superview, and the bounds is it's placement in its own coordinate system. By using bounds the frame of the subview will be 0,0,width,height every time. 3) Since I'm laying out views, I call super when my layout changes are complete. I could be wrong, but since it's viewDIDLayoutSubviews it seems all views should be layed out when super is called.